# failing to make uploaded images folder static

Tags: node.js

I have a backend api that uploads images. How do i make the uploaded images folder accessible on the browser

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './upload/images',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder publicly accessible using following code and then you can access the files from browser using their path. Put this code in app.js (or server.js) file.

```js
...
const path = require('path')
app.use('/upload', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'upload')))
...
```

Access them something like this-

```
http://localhost:3000/upload/images/image.png
```